# Can I add a mouse over sound to this?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I have a code that has a rollover images and when clicked displays a pop up.  I'm not sure why but I am having trouble adding a mouse over sound to it as well.  I appreciate any help thanks!

```
<input name="image" type="image" onMouseOver= src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1roll_15.jpg" onMouseOut= src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1_15.jpg"  value="" src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1_15.jpg" onClick='styledPopupOpen("<img src=http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/flashcards/ichi.gif />")'  align=middle width=131 height=118>
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to use `onMouseOver="this.src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1roll_15.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1_15.jpg'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="image" type="image" value=""
    onMouseOver='this.src = "http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1roll_15.jpg";'
    onMouseOut='this.src = "http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1_15.jpg";'
    src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/images/pk1pg1_15.jpg" onClick='styledPopupOpen("<img src=http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/flashcards/ichi.gif />")' align="middle" width="131" height="118" />
```

UPD: Also may be usable to either preload these images or use single sprite with both over/out states. In the latter case you will manipulate with not `this.src` but `this.style` (if no JS framework is used).

Comment: Thank you guys, but I was looking to have a mouse over (sound) as well.  Where would this code be placed? Thanks so much for your time , I really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, hm... Search about either `Flash` or `HTML5 <audio />`: create element which can play sound, and then call `element.play();` to perform sound.